# Normalize request json in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have an api which accepts some request json. I get the json into an array via `$request->all();`

I then do something with it to compare it to previous requests: `$json = json_encode($request->all()); $md5 = md5($json);`

If that md5 matches something that already exists, I do something different, that's not really important here.

What IS important is that I want to somehow normalize the request so that two requests that come in, even if they come in slightly differently, end up with the SAME MD5.

So for example, if someone sends up `{"tracking_code" : "1234", "id" : 5}`, and then another request comes up as `{ "id" : 5, "tracking_code" : "1234"}`, I want my code to output the same md5 for both of those requests.

I can place some limitations on what's allowed to come up to make this job easier: for example, I can assume that the json object is only one level deep -- no nested objects. The limitations on the datatypes are: every value can be a number, string, null, boolean, or array of the other types. No multi-level arrays.

With those limitations, how easy is it to normalize these request arrays so that when I try to md5 the information, the md5s come out the same?

My first thought was that all I would have to do is make sure the keys are in order. Since it's just a single-level object, as long as the keys appear in alphabetical order, `$json = json_encode($requestArray); $md5 = md5($json);` should produce the same output. Am I correct in that assumption?

Maybe there's a library that already does this? Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $requestArray = $request->all();
        ksort($requestArray);
        $json = json_encode($requestArray);
        $md5 = md5($json);
```

This should work, I think, for the majority of my use cases -- I've tested it on a few request arrays and it seems to be doing the job.

Comment: This might do the job but what about integers given as strings?

Comment: You can NOT complicate this by making everything a string. So this along with ksort()(even for deep nested data) should give you 100% correct results.

Comment: integers as strings -- for the keys of the array, or for the values of the array? I'm not sure it matters in either case, I think I'm ok with assuming that it will be sent up with type-consistency in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible if you process `tracking_code` and `id` concat and then hash it.
so `{"tracking_code" : "1234", "id" : 5}` and `{ "id" : 5, "tracking_code" : "1234"}` will resulting same hash.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Keep in mind that 'tracking_code' and 'id' are not guaranteed to be the only keys, or to even be in there at all. The solution will have to work regardless of what keys actually exist.